# Setting constraints to UIStackview

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, uistackview

I've recently started to use UIStackViews auto layout, but keep running into warnings like the ones on the screenshot and I'm not sure how to make them go away.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kjhf6.png) [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69Vso.png)[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qlnb.png)[image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKSIU.png)[image5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a0eo.png)Any help would be appreciated.

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4aUp.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7knK.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcPO0.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ti3IH.png
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMTrj.png
  [6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LJh7.png
```

Comment: Did you constrain your stackview? You have to constrain the stackview fully..

Comment: Please add more details, show the constraints in the size inspector. It's hard to tell what is wrong...

Comment: do i need to set contraints for each of the individual stackviews after pinning all four sides of the superior stackview to the actual view @Brandon

Comment: show all your constraints. it's not at the top level. one of the inner stackviews constraints are causing the ambiguity

Comment: @staticVoidMan I'm not quite sure what you mean, i've pinned the top stackview with all the other stackview embedded in it, to the 4 sides of the main view

Comment: @AaronOwusu Share your project with only this problem and I will have a look.

Comment: @staticVoidMan https://mega.nz/#F!JdADACiJ!OSQSEV9Ur5WE2-qM5eUVSQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many `UIView`s in your `stackView` and a `UIView` does not have any intrinsic height so there is ambiguity.
The `stackView` basically does not know what height to set for the inner `uiview` elements and consequently at what y position they will start.

#### Solution #1:

- Select the topmost `stackView` that contains all your other `stackView`s and in it's Attributes Inspector, change it's distribution to `Fill Proportionally`.
- Give X & Y position for the back button

[image: Solution #1]

---

#### Solution #2:

- You give a height constraint to each `UIView` (your `backButtonView`, `titleView`, etc.) except for the last one `bottomSpace`

[image: Solution #2]

---

Besides, you have nested `stackView`s unnecessarily. Also, you don't **have** to do everything in a `stackView`.

The first view looks like you want a top bar with a back button. You should be using a `navigationBar` with a `navigationItem` which need not and should not be in a `stackView` unless your design has a special requirement.

The last view looks like you want to leave space so you have a `bottomSpace` view in a `stackView` and both of these are unnecessary.

#### Solution #3

- Redesign your layout and simplify it further.
  For your layout, you can make do with a single `stackView` btw.

As an example, it's not exactly as per your design but near about:
[image: Solution #3]

Comment: Thanks the warnings have disappeared. Really Appreciate the help, and also you're right, some of the stackviews are unnecessary. I will restart with a much simpler design.

Comment: I've decided to go with your first solution on the basis that it works well with the design that I'm after. However when setting constraints to my label I find myself with the following error: http://prntscr.com/ifps18 and when i add the trailing constraint with the greater than or equal relation, i get the following warning: http://prntscr.com/ifpu5e

Comment: @AaronOwusu Are you sure it is the label causing that warning? In your second screenshot, that warning is still there plus a new one. It's a bit difficult to help like this. Basically you need to familiarize yourself with the autolayout engine some more. I will still help as much as I can through comments

Comment: Have you got any suggestions as to where i can learn more about autolayout, youtube has some examples but they're not really  relevant to the things i want to create.

Comment: @AaronOwusu Understand AutoLayout, it's possibilities & limitations, & then rethink your design and go for it. Try this tutorial: https://cocoacasts.com/welcome-to-auto-layout-fundamentals